# Is it possible to customize the httpInterceptors angular6?

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-http-interceptors

I have started working on angular 6 and I am calling different APIs with authentication header. I am using httpInterceptors to add AUth header which seems to work fine. However I have a requirement where some of the APIs need different auth header /or some of the properties of auth header than the other ones.Is there any way to customize the interceptors where I can intercept one request in one way and other in different way?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you could just recognize url and execute diffrent method for diffrent urls.

Comment: Thanks @PatrykBrejdak.. it did work.check the url in interceptor and then modify the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iquery said. You can check in your intercepter with a regex your url. And based on that do your auth logic.
Another option would be to create different intercepters, based on your auth logic and extend from the base intercepter.

Comment: Thanku @Laurentiu